# if condition variables in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

a simple request, but can't find any sample for it.

suppose, I'd like to set an environment variable, depends on the branch name.

something like this (of course, this code doesn't work)

```
variables:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "master"'
      variables:
        env: "dev"
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
      variables:
        env: "prod"
  stackName: projectA-${env}
```

So the stackName or other variables can use `${env}` as suffix in the name and I can also use `${env}` in jobs , scripts or stages

How can I set it?

Answer (score 2):

The variable `env` or `stackName` can be set in two different job, which run with a rule according the branch. And you can define a template job, to make same thing for both environment. For example, define two jobs like this with a template :

```
.template-job:
  script:
    - echo $STACK_NAME

prod-job:
  variables:
    STACK_NAME: projectA-prod
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
  extends: .template-job

dev-job:
  variables:
    STACK_NAME: projectA-dev
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "master"'
  extends: .template-job
```

Using this, you have two jobs but they extends the same `template-job`, which is using the variable `$STACK_NAME`. You can of course name it `ENV` or whatever.

Comment: thanks. But suppose, not only one job need this variable to be set, but 10+ jobs, and not only one variable, but  10+ variables. do i have to add them in each job? my purpose, on top, set all variables, but for different enviroments.

Comment: and what's the purpose of "rules` in your codes, remove them, has no difference.

Comment: Rules are here to define when the job should run, so what value should take the variable.
This is a way to set all variables for different environment according the branch name, so yes, you have to duplicate your variables between all jobs (environments) and then you can use them.

Comment: @Bill note the extends. You can have common parts of the workflow defined in a template. Also you can define multiple variables within each `variables` block here. But yes, defining lots of conditional build steps gets a little redundant. But this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in this way.

```
  environment:
    name: your-env-dev
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master" && "your-env-dev" =~ $YOUR_INSTANCES'
```

Set the variable value in settings under CI/CD

Comment: I can understand the usage of `environment`, but not familar the usage of `rules`.can you share details on it?

Answer (score 0):

Answer my question after about 1 year. Here is my solution, and a simple  solution.

I refered the idea from @Time recommended.

[gitlab pipeline's environments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/) are similar concept of [CircleCI's context](https://circleci.com/docs/contexts/) , if you are familar it.

- create environments first, such as develop, staging, production, etc
- create variables but assigned to different environments

[image]

- you can set the variables with same names, but assigned to different environments.

When use it, you can add below codes to each task

```
staging_build:
  stage: build
  environment:
    name: staging
  script:
    - echo ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
  only:
    - staging

production_build:
  stage: build
  environment:
    name: production
  script:
    - echo ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
  only:
    - main
```